# Quantum entanglement and relativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-entanglement

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding the interplay between special relativity (more specifically the relativity of simultaneity) and quantum entanglement.
Imagine there are two observers, as shown in the figure with the first having the standard coordinate system and the other having the line spanning CI as its time dimension and CB as its space dimension.
At A let both observers make a measurement of a particle's spin and find it to be pointing downward. Now  an entangled partner is measured continuously from B through H to E in the vertical direction and is obviously found to be pointing upward. According to the standard observer this all takes place before a measurement is taken at C at a 60-degree angle, in which the particle is found to be pointing upward (which would happen with $\cos^2(2\pi/3)=1/4$ probability).
This is all fine except for the fact that according to the other observer, due to relativity of simultaneity, measurement C happens before the many measurements between H and E and so (as is seen from the diagram) it could potentially happen that in the measurement immediately following C between H and E the particle is found to be pointing downward, which can't be explained from the first observers point of view.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know if I understand well your question, but the measurement results are as they are, i.e. the relevant events here are (e.g.) observer 1 measures up, observer 2 measures down. The order of measurements might be frame-dependent, but this only changes, well, the order.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be missing a few things:

(1) Measurement breaks entanglement, so after the first measurement the particles are no longer entangled. In particular it doesn't make sense to speak of a "continuous" measurement of an entangled particle. Only the first measurement taken of the particle will be correlated with its distant partner.

(2) Entanglement is about correlation, not necessarily causation. If A and B are space like separated measurements of entangled particles then they will be correlated in a particular way, but there's no way to say that A caused B or B caused A.

Comment: With respect to the first point doesn't the Bell test require the particles to be entangled even after the first measurement?

Comment: No, it requires the use of a number of similarly prepared entangled pairs.

Comment: @Nikolairiberskånstrøm :  Easy homework problem:  Prove that immediately after a measurement (in any basis!) of one particle from an entangled pair, the pair is no longer entangled.

Comment: @WillO This only holds if the corresponding observable is non-degenerate, no?

Comment: @TobiasFünke :  Point taken.   But the OP seems to have implicitly assumed a two-dimensional state space and a measurement with two possible outcomes, which should suffice.

Comment: The answer is correct, but a couple of nuances need to be added: (1) after an entangled particle is measured on some basis, that particle will no longer exhibit entanglement on that basis. You can't really make the same statement about the other particle, regardless of timing/order/basis.(2) It is absolutely correct to say that there is no empirical evidence that the first measurement "causes" the outcome of the second measure, or vice versa. Only by assumption is order a causal factor.

Comment: @Nikolairiberskånstrøm any choice of single particle* basis ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble understanding the interplay between special
> relativity (more specifically the relativity of simultaneity) and
> quantum entanglement.

The simple answer to this: there is *no* interplay between special relativity and entanglement.  No quantum predictions (usually around correlations and/or Bell inequalities) depend in any way on relativistic considerations.

More specifically: the order of measurements makes no observable change whatsoever, regardless of the frame of the observer.  This is essentially what the spacetime diagram shows.  (As pointed out in Eric Smith's answer, you cannot measure a particle repeatedly and expect to see entangled behavior continue for that particle.)

To drive this point home, here are experimental demonstrations where you can easily see relativity can be ignored.  Here are a couple of such.  Note that these papers do not mention relativity, and that is generally true of papers on entanglement.

a) [Characterizing the nonlocal correlations of particles that never interacted](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1314) (2009)

"*It is natural to expect that correlations between distant particles are the result of causal influences originating in their common past — this is the idea behind Bell’s concept of local causality [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1314). Yet, quantum theory predicts that measurements on entangled particles will produce outcome correlations that cannot be reproduced by any theory where each separate outcome is locally determined by variables correlated at the source. This nonlocal nature of entangled states can be revealed by the violation of Bell inequalities.
"However remarkable it is that quantum interactions can establish such nonlocal correlations, it is even more remarkable that particles that never directly interacted can also become nonlocally correlated. This is possible through a process
called entanglement swapping [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0201134). Starting from two independent pairs of entangled particles, one can measure jointly one particle from each pair, so that the two other particles become entangled, even though they have no common past history. The resulting pair is a genuine entangled pair in every aspect, and can in particular violate Bell inequalities.*"

b) And just to drive a nail through it: You can entangle particles AFTER they have already been detected
[Experimental Nonlocality Proof of Quantum Teleportation and Entanglement Swapping](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0201134) (2002-2008)

See middle of page 5:
*"A seemingly paradoxical situation arises — as suggested by Peres [4] — when Alice’s Bell state analysis is delayed long after Bob’s measurements. This seems paradoxical, because Alice’s measurement projects photons 0 and 3 into an entangled state after they have been measured. Nevertheless, quantum mechanics predicts the same correlations. Remarkably, Alice is even free to choose the kind of measurement she wants to perform on photons 1 and 2. Instead of a Bell-state measurement she could also measure the polarizations of these photons individually. Thus depending on Alice’s later measurement, Bob’s earlier results either indicate that photons 0 and 3 were entangled or photons 0 and 1 and photons 2 and 3. This means that the physical interpretation of his results depends on Alice’s later decision.
"Such a delayed-choice experiment was performed by including two 10 m optical fiber delays for both outputs of the BSA. In this case photons 1 and 2 hit the detectors delayed by about 50 ns. As shown in Fig. 3, the observed fidelity of the entanglement of photon 0 and photon 3 matches the fidelity in the non-delayed case within experimental errors. Therefore, this result indicate that the time ordering of the detection events has no influence on the results and strengthens the argument of A. Peres: **this paradox does not arise if the correctness of quantum mechanics is firmly believed.** "*